# Enumerating my method to handle any time out issue

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have below code which is going to copy records from one container in cosmos db to another container in cosmos db. I am just worried on not following the best practices and below code might time out when querying the whole database to get only result with "ClassID". I would appreciate any suggestion as what should I improve in below code. make it async/sync and how can I enumerate in order to overcome any issues in future. As this is an Azure Function which will run first time from beginning but going forward it will be triggered only when there is any changes in Cosmos Db

```
namespace MigrateDbWithChangeFeed
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "databaseName",
            collectionName: "collectionName",
            StartFromBeginning = true,
            ConnectionStringSetting = "",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases",
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true
    )] IReadOnlyList<Document> source, DocumentClient client,
    ILogger log  )
        {
            string continuationToken = null;
            string collectionUrl = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri( "databaseName", "SourceCollection" ).ToString();
            do
            {
                var feed = client.CreateDocumentQuery(
                           collectionUrl,
                           new SqlQuerySpec( "select * FROM c WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.ClassId)" ),
                           new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 10, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true, RequestContinuation = continuationToken } ).AsDocumentQuery();
                var result = feed.ExecuteNextAsync().Result;
                var itemCount = result.Count;
                continuationToken = result.ResponseContinuation;
                foreach( var doc in result )
                {
                    var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( doc.ToString() );
                    string partitionkeyValue = string.Concat( data["ClassId"].Value<string>(), "|", data["Project"].Value<string>() );
                    data.Add( new JProperty( "PartitionKey", partitionkeyValue ) );
                    await client.CreateDocumentAsync( UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
                   "SourceDatabase", "TargetCollection" ),
                   data );

                }
            }
            while( continuationToken != null );
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Review, if you think it can be applied to your question you can add the tag `azure-cosmosdb` or another tag related to databases.

Comment: implemented await..thanks

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Azure Functions and CosmosDb, so I won't review your code from API consumption perspective.

Here are my observations:

- `FunctionNameAttribute`: Please prefer [nameof operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) over hard-coded values

  - If you rename your class (from `Function1`) then the hard-coded value will
    not change with it accordingly
  - On the other hand if you need to refer `Function1` elsewhere in your cloud application then create a [static class where you store your constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842590/static-constants-in-c-sharp)
- `collectionUrl`: I think you don't need to create a separate variable for this, you can simply inline it

  - `CreateDocumentQuery` does have an [overload which accepts an Uri](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.idocumentclient.createdocumentquery?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_IDocumentClient_CreateDocumentQuery_System_Uri_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_SqlQuerySpec_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_FeedOptions_)

```
client.CreateDocumentQuery(
    UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("databaseName", "SourceCollection"),
    new SqlQuerySpec("SELECT * FROM c WHERE IS_DEFINED(c.ClassId)"),
    new FeedOptions { ... });
```

- `feed.ExecuteNextAsync().Result`: Please [prefer async calls over blocking sync calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464287/what-is-the-difference-between-await-taskt-and-taskt-result)
- `result.Count`: As I said I'm not familiar with this API but I would suggest to do some checks on the `FeedResponse` [object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedresponse-1?view=azure-dotnet) to make sure that your issued operation has succeeded before you start to consume it
- `itemCount`: As I can see it is unused so you can freely get rid of it
- `(JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`: Please prefer [JObject.Parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm) to semi parse json strings

  - Please also bear in mind that this might [throw exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830198/newtonsoft-jobject-parse-throws-base-exception-how-to-handle/29830612) (`JsonReaderException`) if not valid json is retrieved for whatever reason
- `data["ClassId"]`: Please prefer [TryGetValue method](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_TryGetValue.htm) over index operator in production code

  - You can examine data existence before you start to using it
- `data["ClassId"].Value<string>()`: You can convert the `JToken` to `string` with simple casting: `(string)data["ClassId"]`
- `string.Concat`: Please prefer [string interpolation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) over explicit call of concat.
- `data.Add(new JProperty ...)`: I think you don't need to create a `JProperty` explicitly, there is an other [overload](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Add.htm), which accepts the same as the JProperty constructor
- `var data`: Please try to use better naming than this, `data` is meaningless
- `continuationToken != null`: Please prefer `string.IsNullOrEmpty` over direct null check against string variable

---

**UPDATE**: How to use `TryGetValue`

ZZZSharePoint has pointed out that the provided link for `TryGetValue` is insufficient to put theory into practice. So, here is my suggestion how to apply that function onto this problem:

```
const string classIdFieldName = "ClassId", projectFieldName = "Project";
const string collectionName = "SourceCollection", partitionKeyFieldName = "PartitionKey";
            
var semiParsedFetchedRecord = JObject.Parse(doc);
if(!semiParsedFetchedRecord.TryGetValue(classIdFieldName, out var classIdField))
    throw new MissingFieldException(collectionName, classIdFieldName);

if (!semiParsedFetchedRecord.TryGetValue(projectFieldName, out var projectField))
    throw new MissingFieldException(collectionName, projectFieldName);

semiParsedFetchedRecord.Add(partitionKeyFieldName, $"{classIdField} | {projectField}");
```

- I've introduced several constants to make maintenance (and reuse) easier
- I've used `JObject.Parse` to get a semi-parsed json (I've renamed your `data` variable to express what's stored inside it)
- I've used `TryGetValue` to make data retrieval operation safe

  - I've used here the [out var](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables) feature of C# to make the code more concise
  - otherwise we need to declare a `JToken` variable before the
    `TryGetValue` call
- I've used [`MissingFieldException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.missingfieldexception) to indicate that something expected is missing

  - `ArgumentException` might be a good choice as well
  - Or if we can ignore those records where the expected fields are missing then a simple `continue` might be okay as well
- Last but not least I've inlined the `partitionKey` calculation

  - Here I've took advantage of the [JToken's explicit conversion operators](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit.htm)

Comment: wow!! people like you are reason why Stack-exchange is so successful. THANKS!!! I did all changes but cant figure out TryGetValue method. How do I do that? I didnt get any idea from the link.

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint I've extended my post with that, please check it again.